# React Native Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Tags: ios, react-native, npm

Getting the following error and not 100% sure why. Currently getting this issue when I run my app in ios simulator

I've tried to do npm install watchman, But I just saw the latest update on the npm packages and it seems like it's been depreciated.

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError 
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:133:12) {
  errno: -24,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  filename: null
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This error was caused by watchman.

You should run `brew install watchman` in the terminal.

If watchman fails to install, you should change the ownership of these directories to your user by

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/var/log
```

please refer to the tips in your terminal.

Finally you run  `brew install watchman`. The problem should be solved.

Comment: Wow, this worked. I don't know why though. I could run my tests in one repo but not another with almost the same stack.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me. Running `brew reinstall watchman` finally fixed the error (had to do `xcode-select --install` for it to work too).

Answer (score 4):

For people with Mac M1 who are running into this problem, I tried the above brew install and upgrade watchman but they didnt work. My specific problem was that react-native project would build on the simulator fine through 'npm run ios' but when archiving or building through xcode I would get this error. After hours upon hours this is what did:

- Go into your Security in your System Preferences of your Mac and give full disk access to watchman
- The project you are building for some reason (Probably because Apple restricts access) does not work when in your Desktop or your Documents location. Once I moved it to under /Users/myname/ it finally built and archived in xcode.

Hopefully this will save someone else the 6 hours I spent debugging and trying to figure out this.

EDIT: THIS BROKE AGAIN SO HAD TO FOLLOW THIS NEXT TO FIX IT:

This error is because of a bug in module fsevents for mac m1 silicon. See the thread: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/668

It got fixed with new version of watchman. Upgrade your watchman through brew. Delete your project and download from git and rebuild everything along with pod install and then it should archive no problem.

Comment: hi @Ekram i'm facing same issue while archive. i've updated watchman to 2021.06.07.00 still i'm facing this issue. any help?

Comment: Can you try  creating an empty React native project from scratch with the latest node, react native and watchman and try archiving? Some of my friends have reported success via this method. If this works you can then narrow down whats the problem in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything and realized there was no fsevents in my node_modules (even though it's a newly properly created react native project), did 'npm install fsevents' and this solved the issue.

Comment: I faced a similar issue when using the react labs on Coursera. and using the npm install fixed it.