# Excel add-in : Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Tags: excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

Created custom function project by following the tutorial as stated in Microsoft docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows

node version : v16.16.0
npm version : 8.11.0
webpack 5.52.1

After starting the dev server (sudo npm run dev-server), getting the following exception

Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

See whether the following solution could resolve your problems.
[React Native Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232960/react-native-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-watch)

It seems a Webpack issue. For your reference:
https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/169